# Pop up Information windows D7

Tags: views, rules, navigation, redirection, javascript

I am new in Drupal 7. What i am trying to do is to show pop up information windows for the following case:

I have a view with links (internal links to drupal site). I want by clicking on them:

1.To show an information pop-up window with the message "Redirection to the official position..."

2. This message to be showing for 3 seconds and
3. The message to disappear after 3 seconds and the redirection to be completed.

How can i show specific pop-up windows by clicking a link and before the redirection takes place?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a contrib module to achieve this, but you can always use jQuery in your theme or custom module.

Something like this might work (not tested, but that's the main idea - out of scope for Drupal Answers):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  // on link click (jQuery 1.4)
  jQuery('#my-link').click(function(e) {
    // preventDefault otherwise browser will go to link
    e.preventDefault();
    // show the pop-up layer which is assumed hidden with css or sth.
    jQuery('#my-popup-layer').fadeIn();
    // here you can possibly chain up more actions in order to 
    // update the contents of the pop-up
    // now delay 3sec
    jQuery(this)
      .delay(3000)
      .queue(function(next) {
        // redirect
        window.location.href = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        next(); // prob redundant
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: i can't solve my problem with this way, because i have a lot of links and i can't substitute each link in '#my-link' to jQuery click form. Except of this, these links are added from users  dynamically,

Comment: You have a Views view, don't you? A view which outputs all relevant links? You do not need to reference each link individually, this is just an example. You can use a jQuery selector to the field's link, eg. `jQuery('.view-my-view .views-row .views-field-my-link a')`.

Comment: I want to combine the Rules and Messages modules to do this, because i am not good in jQuery and probably i will have problems

Comment: Your requirement cannot be fulfilled server-side and you would need at least a module that can provide the js logic. Neither modules seem to me to be able to help.